# Verb tenses in hypothetical situations

Tags: grammar, verbs, tense, aspect

I'm wondering how Japanese tenses work for hypothetical situations that may happen or could have happened.

More specifically, are the verb tenses in the below sentences correct?

> We probably would not have come this far without his support.
>
> 彼の支援がなかったら、ここまで進んで**なかった**でしょう。
>
> If you don't hurry, you will be late for school.
>
> 急がないと遅刻**する**よ

I have seen [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/correct-verb-tenses-for-if-would-type-sentences) as well, but I'm wondering about present and future situations as well.

Comment: They are correct.

Comment: @user4092 Thank you! If it is all right, would you mind posting an answer? That way, I can close this question and give you appropriate credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are very correct. **~ないと** is a very common usage for hypothetical future tense.

I would like to just point out that in your first past tense that the "if" is actually implied by **なかったら** in the prior phrase, not **なかった** in the second, like so:

> 彼の支援が**なかったら**、ここまで進んでなかったでしょう。

and my translation

> **If it were not** for his support, we probably would not have come this far.

Comment: How would it be different if it were "If it **had not been** for his support, we probably would not have come this far"? What would the Japanese sentence be?

Comment: @chocolate Regarding the phrases "if it had not been" and "if it weren't for", I find them to be equivalent for the most part, but there are situations where one is more preferable than the other. Related: http://fromexperience.info/grm/ifitwerenotfor.html / http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/192176-Were-it-not-for-vs-Had-it-not-been-for-vs